# Simple Automatic Backup Solution for Magento?

Tags: backup, magento

I've recently started work on developing a site using Magento.

All of my files and DB are on a linux-based remote web hosting server.

What I'd like to implement is some sort of system where all of my files and the database are backed up once per day "just in case". I'd also like to be able to use the same system to manually back everything up before making any major changes.

I've explored using a solution like Git or SVN in conjunction with CRON MySQL dumps; but they seem to be overkill for my needs.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for taking the time to read this and reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not as much of an overkill solution as you think. SVN (or any other source control system) will let you keep perfect records of how your system looked at any previous time, so when you blow up your website with new code (which happens often when developing Magento), you can quickly restore it to any previous state.

You will especially find this useful when it doesn't become apparent that everything exploded until several days afterward. Hope that helps.

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Thanks for your input Joe. After seeing your response and doing some more research, I've decided to implement SVN.

Answer (score 3):

This article explains how to move Magento to another server

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/moving_magento_to_another_server

You could use point 1 and 2 to backup your sql dump and the important magento folders with the help of a daily cron job.

Comment: Thanks for the link, Julien. I think I've decided to go with Subversion after all.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new extension for scheduled Magento DB backups - [Magento Autobackup](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Customy/extension/7440/autobackup)

Comment: MageBayVaporated out of existence - Dead Link

Answer (score 0):

We use this service to backup magento: http://magento-backups.com/  They combine version control w/ database dumps and keep it all offsite. They're having a special for like $130/yr. Setup was super easy - only took about 10 mins including subversion install. And customer service was on point when we had troubles.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that I just posted to another question here. I also use git, but it's nice to just grab a tar of the files, scp or ftp them to a different server and upload it.

The next step would be to make a script that changes the base urls and the payment gateway to "test". Maybe another day!

[Magento: Backup Advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497876/magento-backup-advice/8541295#8541295)

Relevent info:

I prefer nightly backups for magento. This isn't for record keeping, but it's for shit hits the roof type senarios. If something really goes bad, you're better off getting the store up and running ASAP and worrying about open orders and lost sales information once the store is up.

The backup script is crude, but it makes a gziped copy of the database and file directory in a directory that you can make for backups. It appends the month and day to the files. You need to make sure the user has the correct permissions to tar the magento file structure.

```
!/bin/sh
m_user='databaseusername'
m_pass='databasepasswd'
db_name='databasename'
od='/home/user/backups/website/' #output directory of the backups
id='/var/www/html/' #the location of the site
name=$od$db_name
name+="_"
mysqldump --opt -u $m_user -p$m_pass $db_name | gzip -c | cat > $name$(date +%m-%d).sql.gz; tar -zcvf $name$(date +%m-%d).tar.gz $id
```