# Magento: Backup Advice

Tags: mysql, database, magento, e-commerce, backup

This could just as well apply to any ecommerce system such as Magento.

I have a new Magento installation and I want to be prepared for when the client asks me about backups. I am aware of all (or most) of the methods of taking backups, and also the various bits that are protected by each type, however the concern I have is to do with open orders. What happens to orders placed after the most recent DB backup in the event of a restore? I presume a DB backup would store the open orders on the system, however obviously I cant be taking and storing backups every second of the day.

So what happens to the orders taken after the last backup if the database gets corrupted and needs to be restored? I presume there'd be at least a chance that some orders might be lost. Am I wrong? If not, then what is standard practice for this ? The goods my client is selling are not that cheap, so typical orders are at least into hundreds (of euro).

Comment: I totally misread that and thought it was magneto...

Comment: You have a lot of options for tackling this, including some sort of database redundancy. Some of your options have a pretty hefty budget, so you may want to include that in your details. I'd first consider whether or not you have to rely on a backup as your only source of redundancy.

Comment: @melee thanks - I hadn't thought of that - presumably running a mirror copy of the DB is the only watertight solution, am i right ?

Comment: @byronyasgur watertight? I wouldn't say that. Think of it like a RAID array - if one DB goes down, that shouldn't bring down the system. There should be others in place to take the load while the downed copy is brought back to life. This insurance isn't cheap, though.

Comment: @melee yes, not cheap at all - I was on to my host - i dont think anything like this is for us to be honest, it's a fairly low turnover site, but i'm glad to appreciate the principle thanks. Also from the answer below it got me thinking that the admin would at least have the notification emails to go by so it should be survivable. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 things I can think of right now:

1) Setup replication. This will ensure that your backup is always up to date and that you can quickly switch to the slave in case something happens to the master.

2) Export an order automatically, once an order is completed. You can make use of magento's event/observer implementation to export orders to other systems or to just send plain copies to some email address, depending on what exactly you want to backup.

Comment: Thanks - is setup replication the same thing as database redundancy - had a quick google and it seems similar

Comment: Reeplication is not a backup. I like your second option, however i think it's necessary to observe many events not just that.

Answer (score 4):

I know the answer was already selected, but for others that may go here I may as well throw in some input.

I prefer nightly backups for magento. This isn't for record keeping, but it's for *shit hits the roof* type senarios. If something really goes bad, you're better off getting the store up and running ASAP and worrying about open orders and lost sales information once the store is up.

The backup script is crude, but it makes a gziped copy of the database and file directory in a directory that you can make for backups.  It appends the month and day to the files. You need to make sure the user has the correct permissions to tar the magento file structure.

```
!/bin/sh
m_user='databaseusername'
m_pass='databasepasswd'
db_name='databasename'
od='/home/user/backups/website/' #output directory of the backups
id='/var/www/html/' #the location of the site
name=$od$db_name
name+="_"
mysqldump --opt -u $m_user -p$m_pass $db_name | gzip -c | cat > $name$(date +%m-%d).sql.gz; tar -zcvf $name$(date +%m-%d).tar.gz $id
```

I also grab all order, customer, and item info and store them in a separate server, but it's for a different business purpose.